# bash native string manipulation displays jumbled output

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I tried to use the bash string native manipulation for substituting string with my shell variables.

```
var1='123'
var2='2018-01-01'
var3='2018-01-02'
var4='myfunction('var1','var2','var3')'

var5=${var4/var1/$var1}
echo $var5

var5=${var5/var2/$var2}
echo $var5

var5=${var5/var1/$var3}
echo $var5
```

Expected output:

```
myfunction('123','var2','var3')
myfunction('123','2018-01-01','var3')
myfunction('123','2018-01-01','2018-01-02')
```

Actual output with jumbled strings:

```
myfunction('123','var2','var3')
myfunction('123','2018-01-01','var3')
')function('123','2018-01-01','2018-01-02
```

Here the last two characters shift at the beginning and I lose the first two characters of the string.
I can use SED for the same. But I am just trying to figure out why will the bash native string manipulation not work as expected. Is it because I am doing multiple substitutions ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. But try quoting your assignements: `var5="${var4/var1/$var1}"` as well as `echo "$var5"`.

Comment: Your third substitution should be `var5=${var5/var3/$var3}` and if you want to keep the single quotes in `myfunction('var1','var2','var3')`, you should define `var4` using `var4="myfunction('var1','var2','var3')"`. But I can't see a reason why the output should be jumbled.

Comment: That's not the output of that script. First of all, you're never replacing `var3`, but `var1` twice. Second, your `var4` does not have any single quotes within it, but somehow the output has them anyway. Please post the _exact_ script you use when asking for help online, the details _matter_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a carriage return (CR) character at the end of `var3` content. After it gets printed without immediately following newline character (line feed, LF), the remaining part of the line is printed from the left edge, overwriting the already printed beginning of the line.

Unix standard of line ending is LF, not CR LF.

Rewrite the script line where the variable is defined or use `dos2unix` on the file.

Comment: dos2unix solved the problem!! Thanks so much @Kamil :)